# Android replace shortcut icon with widget to replicate mail unread functionality

Tags: android, widget, icons, homescreen

Is it possible to replace your App's default shortcut icon with a widget so you can for example replicate the mail unread functionality? I've been googling ALOT and I have found tons of ways to make the actual widget and also a bunch of people saying that the app icon is static i.e. it can't be changed without a software update. So my question is:

Can I change so when the user drags my app from the "program" tab to the homescreen - can it show the widget instead of the actual icon?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have your application icon be a widget in the application drawer.

No, you cannot automatically convert a shortcut  the user places on the homescreen to a widget.

Widgets and application shortcuts are two separate entities, and must be explicitly created by the user. They get to choose which one they want.